# Stuck in Infinite Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, maze

I have this function to solve a maze in C++, but when I run the program I get a Bad Access Error in the recursion. I think in may be an infinite loop. I have no idea where and what is going wrong.

```
bool Solve_Maze(int coorx,int coory) {
    if((Map[coorx][coory]==Start)||(Map[coorx][coory]==path)) {
        Map[coorx][coory]=wall;
        Solve_Maze(coorx+1,coory);
        Solve_Maze(coorx-1,coory);
        Solve_Maze(coorx,coory+1);
        Solve_Maze(coorx,coory-1);
    }else if(Map[coorx][coory]==End) {
        cout<<"You Solved the Maze!"<<endl;
        delete Map;
        return(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on Map but you should probably check if coorx and coory are valid coordinates/values for Map

Comment: They are, I displayed the coordinates before the if statement and everything worked as expected(first set of coor was the Start and every other coor was path).

Comment: I don't see where you mark a spot as having been travelled.  At first glance, it seems like you could very easily go back and forth and never end.  (I'd think you'd blow your stack, though.)

Comment: @Marvo I mark the spot when making the Map[current location] = wall.

Comment: Support `coorx` is zero. You happily call `Solve_Maze(-1, ..`. That leads to accessing the `Map` array out of bounds.

Comment: Are you doing the line "Map[coorx][coory]=wall;" to mark a spot as visited?

Comment: @JaredSealey the if statement checks if it is path or start, so yes wall is visited.

Comment: Well, you probably should mark it as visited instead of overloading the meaning of wall.

Answer (score 2):

1) You are not returning any value in if statement
2) Map[coorx][coory] always assigned to wall in all function call..Does wall refers to a global state?

Comment: In the class there are 4 private chars, Start, End, wall, and path. They are all valid and the program successfully finds the starting coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the function to return void since the value wasn't properly being returned up the stack. In this case you will just use the global **found** variable to check if the end was found. (this will require you to set 'found = false' every time before you run the function).

```
bool found = false;
```

You also want to do some input validation

```
if( coorx > maxX || coorx < 0 || coory > maxY || coory < 0) return;
```

You will need to replace maxX and maxY with 1 more than your maximum values for coorx and coory. That will ensure you don't get a bad access error.

```
bool found = false; // this will be global scope or pass it by reference
Solve_Maze(x,y);
// if(found) - found will be true if you found the end

void Solve_Maze(int coorx,int coory) {
    if( coorx > maxX || coorx < 0 || coory > maxY || coory < 0) return;
    else if(((Map[coorx][coory]==Start)||(Map[coorx][coory]==path))) {
        Map[coorx][coory]=wall;
        Solve_Maze(coorx+1,coory);
        Solve_Maze(coorx-1,coory);
        Solve_Maze(coorx,coory+1);
        Solve_Maze(coorx,coory-1);
    }else if(Map[coorx][coory]==End) {
        cout<<"You Solved the Maze!"<<endl;
        delete Map;
        found = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it in a debugger (gdb or dbx).  Compile with the -g flag so your program can be debugged.  If you don't know how to use a debugger, google "dbx cheatsheet."  You can isolate where it's stuck in the loop (if your guess is right) and step your way through.  The total time it will take you to become proficient enough in a debugger to do this is, and to actually do it, is less than the amount of time you have spent thinking about it already.

No sarcasm is intended - people really do often overestimate the work in learning a debugger, so I want to really assert the point that it's worth it even for a simple problem, and tremendously pays off for big problems.

Comment: When I run the program it stops with a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error at the if statement. When I debug it, it keeps running through the recursion until once again I get a error.

Comment: @JakeRunzer It's not recursion that is the problem, you are not checking to see if the coorx and coory are valid, and you are accessing memory that you do not have permission to read. Aka, not memory owned by your program. Could also be that you are deleting map on the other three iterations of the function after one solves it, but before the buffer is flushed so you don't see the output.

Comment: Yes, failing on that "if" would mean that one of your coorx or coory are out of range of your array.  So, figure out what to do when that happens and code for it.

Comment: Thank you. I checked to make sure the points were valid and it worked perfectly. Stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: To make it easier to test, consider making your grid smaller.  A 3x3 grid would probably be pretty easy to test out in a debugger.